# Fatal Error when using search bar on Magento Website

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error

Hello dear community,

Apologies in advance if I break any formalities in asking this question.

When using the search bar for our Magento website, it returns a fatal error. "**Fatal error: Call to a member function prepareTerms() on boolean in [file path] on line 341"**.

Line 341 and the prepareTerms() function seems like it is related to a public function prepareResult that begins a few lines above. Here is that entire portion:

```
 public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)
{       
    $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    if (!$query->getIsProcessed()) {
        $searchType = $object->getSearchType($query->getStoreId());

        $preparedTerms = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')
            ->prepareTerms($queryText, $query->getMaxQueryWords());
```

That bottom line is the line **341** that the error message references.

**EDIT** thanks to the comment from rickdenhaan I see now that the issue is with the line **340**  `$preparedTerms = Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')` which seems to not be returning the desired result. If anyone is familiar with how the catalogsearch model is defined that would very likely be a huge help! I am doing more research on this in the meantime. I found this example (under example #9) which looks very similar to what is going on in the file I am trying to troubleshoot. Here is the link: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/Mage/getResourceHelper/php-mage-getresourcehelper-method-examples.html#0xa82d1ee83ee0b30839a7d2a2946c67a0c2bc8f497a62e25aabf1f9508b93c8b8-34,,46,

Would be greatly appreciated if anyone has any ideas of how I can troubleshoot this or if there is any additional information I can provide or look into to further progress on this! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're searching for the wrong thing. "Call to a member function prepareTerms() on boolean" means that the result of `Mage::getResourceHelper('catalogsearch')` is a boolean (probably `false`) instead of an object containing a prepareTerms method. What you need to debug is why there's a problem retrieving the `catalogsearch` helper.

Comment: Thank you very much rick! Do you have any recommended methods for exploring that? The path for the file is app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php - which seems like it would be what contains the resource helper. Is there a standard area where the helper would be defined maybe? Thanks again for your help!. Any recommended reading would be greatly appreciated as well - if not too much trouble :)

Comment: Sorry, no clue. Personally, I would set a breakpoint on line 340 and take things step by step to see what's going on and if it matches what *should* be going on. [Here's](https://deliciousbrains.com/xdebug-advanced-php-debugging/) a blog post about doing that using Xdebug from PhpStorm. Otherwise, perhaps you can find more specialised help at [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com)?